# Autocomplete dynamic search SQL database from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, dynamic

***I have a search box where search is done through database.*** In the code I have, the search is done in one input box and the dynamic search output is shown in a text area below it.

What I want is a *search like Google,* where when the user stars typing, it should show similar items from the db table.

**For example,** if I have two organizations named "Dummy 1" and "Dummy 2" and the user types in "du", the search bar should show the 2 results and user should be able to select one.

The code I have is:

```
<form action="newbrand.php" method="post">
    <br>
    Brand Name: <input type="text" name="bname" /><br><br>
    Search for an Organization: <input type="text" name="search" onkeyup="searchq()" id="output"><  
    Selected Organization:<textarea id="output"></textarea>
</form>
```

The **js** is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function searchq(){
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
    $.post("search.php", {searchVal: searchTxt},function(output){
        $("#output").html(output);
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the search.php file:

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
if(!link){
    echo "DB Connection error";
}
$output = '' ;
$output2 = '' ;
if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
$searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
//$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `organisations_info` WHERE `Organisation_Name` LIKE '%$searchq%'")or die("Could not search!");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
    $output = '<div>No results!</div>';
}else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $orgname = $row['Organisation_Name'];
        $orgid = $row['Organisation_Id'];
        $subs = $row['Subscription_Type'];
        //$output = echo "<option value='".$orgname."'>" . $orgname . "</option>";
        $output = $orgname; 
        $output2 = $orgid; 
        $output3 = $subs;
        //$output = '<div>'.$orgname.'</div>';
    }
}
}
echo ($output);
?>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: try using jQuery autocomplete https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @ShoaibAkhter, for that the items should be listed (hardcoded) in the `availableTags` array. In my case, the items come dynamically from a database

Comment: There are more examples listed on the same page, check REMOTE DATASOURCE example in the right menu https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote, this will allow you to receive dynamic data.

Answer (score 2):

In the JS code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function searchq(){
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
    $.post("search.php", {searchVal: searchTxt},function(output){
        $("#output").html(output);
    }
}
</script>
```

you have given the **id(#output) of a input type element to display(or to return) the HTML statements** and the js script also not closed properly (syntax error).So the **valid statement will be...**

```
<form action="newbrand.php" method="post">
    <br>
    Brand Name: <input type="text" name="bname" /><br><br>
    Search for an Organization: <input type="text" name="search" onkeyup="searchq()" id="output"><  
    Selected Organization:<textarea id="output"></textarea>
</form>
<br>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function searchq(){
        var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
        $.post("search.php", {searchVal: searchTxt},function(output){
        $("#mydiv").html(output);
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your query :

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `organisations_info` WHERE `Organisation_Name` LIKE  '%".$searchq."%' ")or die("Could not search!");
```

And the query will work fine :)

Then *output the response in HTML in your* **search.php** (manage the css accordingly) :

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
if(!link){
    echo "DB Connection error";
}
$output = '' ;
$output2 = '' ;
if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
$searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
//$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `organisations_info` WHERE `Organisation_Name` LIKE  '%".$searchq."%' ")or die("Could not search!");

$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
    $output = '<div>No results!</div>';
}else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $orgname = $row['Organisation_Name'];
        $orgid = $row['Organisation_Id'];
        $subs = $row['Subscription_Type'];
    ?>
        <div><?php echo $orgname; ?></div>';
        <div><?php echo $orgid ; ?></div>';
        <div><?php echo $subs ; ?></div>';
   <?php
    } // while
} // else
} // main if
?>
```

I hope this is what you required !!

Comment: From your code, what happens it that it lists the two items, in the separate `<p>`. I want it to display on the search box it self, like it happens in google. And the user should be able to select one of them

Comment: @YohanBlake, I have removed `<p>` in my question then how is it possible. 
and also u need to manage html accordingly. I just wrote php code for u

Comment: Yeah, I mean, you made changes to the search.php file. The echoes go to the main page and as in my question, it displays in the textarea. I want the results to be shown in the same input box, like a google search bar (autocomplete)

Comment: Either wise you can try to replace the result div with the input type having the same id, @YohanBlake

Comment: So what I tried is, I added a select box to the main file, and echoed the results from the search.php inside `<option>` tags. Now the results are displayed in a select box properly. But what I want to do is to add these results in the same input box the user is typing. Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: @YohanBlake, then you should remove the select box, and directly add it to input box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109501/discussion-between-ms-nehal-and-yohan-blake).